# Loading MathJax into loaded div

Tags: php, html, mathjax

Not entirely sure how to phrase this question.

I have a website that involves the use of MathJax to display math problems. The text on a page is loaded from a separate file based on what someone searches for. So, for example, searching for 'apple' brings up the page for 'apple'. This text is stored in a class in the second php file, and the math equation is typed out in there as well. However, once I load the equation into the page, it doesn't typeset it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">

function compendium()
{
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = '<?php echo $pageTitle ?>';
    document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = '<?php links($pageBody, $new_classes) ?>';
    document.getElementById('nav').innerHTML = '<?php echo $pageNav ?>';
}
</script>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
    displayMath: [['[math]','[math]']]}
});
</script>
```

I'm not entirely sure what to do, but I want it to typeset the euqation once it loads. Anyone know what I can do to do this? The equation is stored as a variable in a class in the secondary file, and printed out. Which it does, however it won't typeset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After each time you load new content call this javascript function

```
function update_mathjax(){
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub,'body']);
}
```

Here `'body'` can be replaced by the id of any div you want to update so you could do something like

```
function update_mathjax(id){
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub,id]);
}
```

then call `update_mathjax('body')` or `update_mathjax('title')`. These are div id's remember, not the html elements. I'm not sure if using the element names themselves would work, but I don't think so...

Comment: Thanks Nick, it works perfect! I didn't understand exactly where to place it though so after some testing it turned out to work by placing it underneath the compendium() function and then called by that function once everything else was loaded. Thanks again, it works exactly as I need it!